# aggregration to return all values not do group by

Tags: elasticsearch

can aggregatin return all values? is there any way to do this with scripts?

```
{
"size": 0,
"_source":["docDescription","datasource"],
"query": {
     "match_all":{}
},
"aggs":{
    "projectNameMatchCount": {
      "filter" : { "match": { "docDescription": ".ppt" } },
      "aggs":{
        "names":{
            "terms":{"field":"_id"}
         }  
      } 
    },
    "datasourceSourceMatchCount": {
        "filter" : { "match": { "datasource": "NGA" } }
    }
}
```

}

in aggeration projectMatchCount, I am applying filter , and call other aggegration, to return  the values, but term will do a group by, I don't want group by, all I want  is return the field values

Comment: From your query, it doesn't like you agg is being used in a correct manner. Can you please explain this with a proper example.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregations are for grouping together data sets to drive a certain metric. If you want individual elements to be returned, you should run direct queries/filter instead. Aggregations are post processes which runs on the data set narrowed down by your query and comparatively expensive than your queries/filter. So, they should be avoided till you need aggregated metrics.

Having said that, from what I understood from your query is that you are using two aggregations. You want one to return some document IDs and the other to just return a count based on a different filter. It is possible to do so by making use of top-hits aggregation within the filter aggregation in projectNameMatchCount. For more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

But still, I believe you will benefit more by simply making two separate queries in terms of total query time and the resources consumed at ElasticSearch side, one with a query to return the IDs and the other with aggregation to return the count of docs.

Comment: is it possible to  concat docDescription  as a comma seperated string?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it via the query itself. You will have to run a script on the result set yourself. But it will be a fairly simple function. Just iterate through the hits in the result set, take the docDescription from the _source and keep concating it.